# Unknown empty space in layout, how to remove it?

Tags: layout, grid, space

I have simple grid layout. 3 columns, 3 rows. Rows are set 400px 400px 100px just for demo.My monitor resolution is 1920x1080 (doesn't matter). On main page there won't content just informations. I'd like remove the empty space under the grid, cuz there is no reason for. I dont know how. It makes my other parts buggy. For better understanding i insert image below.
I checked also `<body>` but it's not this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete it
This is the default HTML and cannot be done unless you override it with an object or change the background color so that it is not white.